# Why overload one parameter template function besides variadic template?

Tags: c++, libstdc++

I read some code from <any> in gcc 10.2.0 [source](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/releases/gcc-10/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/any#L365)

```
    // Manage in-place contained object.
    template<typename _Tp>
      struct _Manager_internal
      {
    static void
    _S_manage(_Op __which, const any* __anyp, _Arg* __arg);

    template<typename _Up>
      static void
      _S_create(_Storage& __storage, _Up&& __value)
      {
        void* __addr = &__storage._M_buffer;
        ::new (__addr) _Tp(std::forward<_Up>(__value));
      }

    template<typename... _Args>
      static void
      _S_create(_Storage& __storage, _Args&&... __args)
      {
        void* __addr = &__storage._M_buffer;
        ::new (__addr) _Tp(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
      }
      };
```

And I can't understand why there are two `_S_create`, the second is superset of the first, isn't it? Can we omit the first one?

Comment: I am with you. I can't see any reason for the specialisation of the single argument version... Maybe you simply write a bug report as this can remove unnecessary code from the libs. Give it a try!

Comment: @Klaus I didn't do it before, should i send email to libstdc++@gcc.gnu.org ?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/

Comment: Have you checked that a default template argument is not provided for the parameter Up in any header file? In this case the secong would be used if the Up is not deducible

Comment: @Evg Thank you, I committed https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96413

Comment: @Oliv sorry, i can't understand, can you show me code?

Comment: @godizzy, Sorry I had not seen that _S_create is a member of a class template, in this specific case, default argument cannot be added. Otherwise the trick I was speaking about consist in giving _Up a default argument, for exemple `typename _Up = initializer_list<int>` in order that the call `_S_create(storage, {1,2,3})` is well formed.